# SQLcl: set color in sqlprompt (ANSI/VT100 Control sequences)

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqlcl

This is my `login.sql`

```
SET sqlprompt "_user'@'_connect_identifier > "
SET sqlformat ansiconsole
SET serveroutput on
SET lines 3000
```

How to set the `sqlprompt` to color red for Prod (and green color for testing)?

Comment: set sqlprompt "@|red _USER|@@@|red _CONNECT_IDENTIFIER|@@|red >|@"

Comment: Check from ThatJeffSmith website,you can set color dynamically based on user or any other unique identifier(I didn't test though).Here is the [link](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2016/09/having-fun-with-prompts-and-saving-yourself-from-mistakes/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From above link I created a Java Script in sqlcli bin directory(on windows 10)

```
C:\sqlcl-19.2.1.246.1707\sqlcl\bin>type PromptColor.js
//file name PromptColor.js save in sqlcli bin dir
//login sqlcli and run script PromptColor.js
var dbUser = util.executeReturnOneCol('select user from sys.dual');
if ( dbUser == 'HR' )
  {
   sqlcl.setStmt('set sqlprompt "@|red _USER|@@@|red _CONNECT_IDENTIFIER|@@|red >|@"');
  }
else if ( dbUser == 'SOE')
  {
    sqlcl.setStmt('set sqlprompt "@|green _USER|@@@|green _CONNECT_IDENTIFIER|@@|green >|@"');
  }

else
  {
    sqlcl.setStmt('set sqlprompt "@|blue _USER|@@@|blue _CONNECT_IDENTIFIER|@@|blue >|@"');
  }


sqlcl.run();
```

login with default prompt

```
C:\sqlcl-19.2.1.246.1707\sqlcl\bin>sql soe/soe@localhost:1521/orclpdb.localdomain -- pdb database 

SQLcl: Release 19.2.1 Production on Tue Nov 12 12:17:13 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.3.0.0.0
SQL>script PromptColor.js
```

[image]

Next is to figure how to call javascript from login.sql

Edit:- create a sql file with single line `script PromptColor.js` place in SQLPATH directory and add that sqlfile name in login.sql it automatically changes color based on user logged in